# Add checkmark next to menu item

Tags: objective-c, menuitem

How can I add a check symbol next to a menu item, like so?
[image: List of possible keyboard inputs]

Also, how do I modify the value associated with it? As of now, I have the following code:

```
//Create the menu

theMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
[theMenu setAutoenablesItems:NO];

[theMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Enabled" action:@selector(logIt) keyEquivalent:@""];
[theMenu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]];

[theMenu addItemWithTitle:@"About" action:@selector(orderFrontStandardAboutPanel:) keyEquivalent:@""];
[theMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Check For Updates" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];

[theMenu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]];

[theMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Quit" action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@""];

NSStatusBar *statusBar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
statusItem = [statusBar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
[statusItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Icon2.png"]];
[statusItem setToolTip:_appName];
[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
[statusItem setMenu:theMenu];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The check is linked to the state of the menuItem.

```
[statusItem setState:NSONState];
```

The check should appear when the item is in ON State

Comment: Should be: `[statusItem setState:NSOnState];`

Comment: FYI: NSOnState is deprecated; use NSControlStateValueOn instead.